# Why boil sugar for lemonade?

Tags: chemistry, drinks, lemonade

I've started making home lemonade recently and all the recipes boil about one cup of sugar in one cup of water. I never questioned that until my father saw the process and asked why don't I just add water and sugar to lemon juice or add boiling water to the pitcher with lemon juice and sugar and I couldn't really tell, I just knew the sweetness was greater in my experience.

Comment: It may not seem like it, but https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/is-lemonade-better-when-made-with-simple-syrup answers your question. "Simple syrup" is the one-cup-sugar-one-cup-water the recipes call for

Answer (score 4):

It's simply to allow the sugar to dissolve and mix into the lemonade.  Because of this, you can more precisely adjust your preferred sweetness level.