# Stirring honey in room temp. water vs. boiling honey water?

Tags: lemonade

I read [Is lemonade better when made with simple syrup?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1237/68642), but does the answer differ if I use honey rathe rthan sugar?

In their videos on making lemonade, [Rachel Farnsworth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtMh1JSRQjA) and [Laura Vitale](https://youtu.be/hxmu13bEQM8) counsel boiling sugar and water to make simple syrup on the stove. But if I prefer honey, ought I add honey to room temp. water and mix them in a blender?

Comment: Just use warm water from the tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honey has volatile flavor compounds like floral overtones or orange flavor which you likely want to keep. High heat will cause you to lose some of these, so I'd advise against boiling. Honey is already a sugar syrup so boiling is totally unnecessary anyway, some heat can help with getting the honey mixed in, but a blender would probably take care of that.