# Is My Vaccum Sealed & Marianted Steak Still Good?

Tags: food-safety, meat

I accidentally left out two raw steaks that were individually vacuum sealed and marinating in Worcestershire and A1 for about 5 hours. They were mostly frozen when I put them out and it's pretty chilly in the kitchen (50F - 55F). When I remembered, they were definitely room temp.

Think they are still good? Everything I read says 2 hours max, but I think this scenario is a bit different.

This was marked as a duplicate question with [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/105342/stirring-honey-in-room-temp-water-vs-boiling-honey-water) and says I have to edit it. Here is my edit: I changed nothing. This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: @rumtscho It looks like you selected an unrelated question when closing as a duplicate – I think an equivalent question definitely exists somewhere (short answer: in food safety guidance terms the vacuum sealing is a red herring) but the one about honey is definitely unrelated.

Comment: @dbmag9 thank you, it was really a completely unrelated question. I corrected the duplicate target.